# dashes and indentations in yaml

Tags: yaml, prometheus

I'm going through the "getting started" [tutorial for Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/getting_started/). I'm getting very hung up on the YAML config file:

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name:       'node'

    # Override the global default and scrape targets from this job every 5 seconds.
    scrape_interval: 5s

    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:8080', 'localhost:8081']
        labels:
          group: 'production'

      - targets: ['localhost:8082']
        labels:
          group: 'canary'
```

So apparently hyphens are supposed to indicate one of two things: The first item in a new list, or a key value pair.

- So it looks like `job_name: 'node'` is a key value pair. Why then is everything after it indented?
- `targets` also looks like a key value pair. But so does `labels` and it doesn't have a hyphen. Further, `group` is indented by one space from `labels`.

It's very, very difficult for me to tell what is going on here. I need to know if I am ever going to customize this file (which I already tried to do and received errors when starting up Prometheus).

What is the logical structure of this file?

Comment: "So apparently hyphens are supposed to indicate one of two things: The first item in a new list, or a key value pair." - No, hypthens (`-`) has the only purpose to indicate **beginning** of **every element** in the list. An element continues until another hyphens or until the end of the list.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

YAML documents consist of three types of nodes: Scalars, sequences and mappings.
When using block syntax, each node exists at a specific indentation level, where its content is defined.

Here's a simple example to make it more clear:

```yaml
-
  a
- 
  b:
    c
-
  -
    d
```

At indentation level 0, there are hyphens defining sequence items. Therefore, the top level node is a sequence.
In the first sequence item, there is an `a`. It is part of the sequence item since it has more indentation.
This is parsed as scalar.

In the second sequence item, there is a mapping that maps the scalar `b` to the scalar `c`. We see that because `b:` is an *implicit key* (a single-line node succeeded by a colon), and the occurrence of an implicit key indicates the existence of a mapping (just like the existence of a sequence item indicates the existence of a sequence). `c` is the value of `b` because again, it is more indented.

Now YAML defines a *compact notation* where you can treat sequence indicators as part of the indentation. Also you can place certain nodes directly after an implicit key. This condenses the example to:

```yaml
- a
- b: c
- - d
```

Still, the key `b:` is completely independent of the sequence item indicator `-`. Now let's apply this to your file:

```yaml
scrape_configs:
  - job_name:       'node'

    # Override the global default and scrape targets from this job every 5 seconds.
    scrape_interval: 5s
    # …
```

The top level is a mapping since there is an implicit key `scrape_configs`. It contains a sequence with one item. This one item is a mapping and starts at `job_name:`. Other keys are `scrape_interval` and `static_configs`. `static_configs` maps to a sequence of mappings, where each mapping contains the keys `targets` and `labels`.

The `[]` syntax is an alterative syntax for defining sequences, usually for short ones that fit on a single line. Scalars can be quoted, which is usually done when values contain YAML special symbols. For example, within `[]` a comma starts the next item, so if you want to have a comma in your scalar, you need to quote the scalar.

So, bottom line: Hyphens and implicit keys are independent structures. Don't read the hyphen as part of the key.